# navigating through different drive letters in python os.system

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I am having a problem with a bit of code on one windows machine but not all windows machines. i have the following code:

```
path = "F:/dir/"
os.system(path[0:2] + " && cd " + path + " && git init")
```

On all but one of my windows systems it runs fine but on a windows 2003 server it gives a "directory not found" error but if i run the same command flat from the command prompt than it works.

I'm sorry if my question comes off as vague but I'm totally stumped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[os.path](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) contains many usefull path manipulation functions.  Probably just handling the path cleanly will resolve your problem.

```
>>> import os
>>>
>>>
>>> path = "F:/dir/"
>>>
>>> clean_path = os.path.normpath(path)
>>> clean_path
'F:\\dir'
>>> drive, directory = os.path.splitdrive(clean_path)
>>> drive
'F:'
>>> directory
'\\dir'
```

Also, you might want to look into using the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module, it gives you more control over processes.

[Replacing Older Functions with the subprocess Module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements)